# Expand ALL and Collapse ALL Table Functionality

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have created tabs for wine regions and collapsible tables to show individual wine data within the tabs using HTML, CSS and Javascript (thanks to W3 Schools).  I am struggling with some functionality to be able to show or hide all wines within the collapsibles at once.

I want to be able to have two options for the collapsible tables: **Expand All** and **Collapse All**.  This is beyond my expertise.

**This is part of the code (Tabs and 1 collapsible table):**

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function openWine(evt, wineName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(wineName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
<style>
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 12.6px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
 }
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
   text-decoration: none;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
   text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wp-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wp-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wp-table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.wp-table th:first-child, 
.wp-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 12px;
}


.wp-table td, 
.wp-table th {
    padding: 4px 4px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.wp-table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12.6px
 }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.wp-table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px
 }
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.wp-table {
    font-size: 12.6px!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.wp-table {
    font-size: 15px!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12.6px;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
}
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.collapsible:after {
  content: '+';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active.collapsible:after {
  content: "-";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.noncollapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12.6px;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.noncollapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
}
.content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.noncollapsecontent {
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 1')" id="defaultOpen">Wine 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 2')">Wine 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 3')">Wine 3</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 4')">Wine 4</button>
</div>

<div id="Wine 1" class="tabcontent">

  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Wine 12</button>
<div class="content">
<table class="wp-table">
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
<th>Col 3</th>
<th>Col 4</th>
</tr><tr><td>10060452000</td><td>2000</td><td>4800</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452008</td><td>2008</td><td>2670</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452009</td><td>2009</td><td>2348</td><td>13/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452010</td><td>2010</td><td>3300</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452011</td><td>2011</td><td>2590</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452012</td><td>2012</td><td>3800</td><td>5/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452013</td><td>2013</td><td>2300</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452014</td><td>2014</td><td>2320</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452015</td><td>2015</td><td>2550</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452016</td><td>2016</td><td>2600</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452017</td><td>2017</td><td>2760</td><td>12/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062051998</td><td>1998</td><td>5740</td><td>8/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052000</td><td>2000</td><td>9450</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052008</td><td>2008</td><td>4332</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr></table> 
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Wine 15</button>
<div class="content">
<table class="wp-table">
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
<th>Col 3</th>
<th>Col 4</th>
</tr><tr><td>10062052009</td><td>2009</td><td>8500</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052010</td><td>2010</td><td>9600</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052011</td><td>2011</td><td>4200</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052012</td><td>2012</td><td>4000</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052013</td><td>2013</td><td>3840</td><td>12/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052014</td><td>2014</td><td>4200</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052015</td><td>2015</td><td>6280</td><td>12/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052016</td><td>2016</td><td>7040</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052017</td><td>2017</td><td>4800</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr></table> 
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Wine 20</button>
<div class="content">
<table class="wp-table">
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
<th>Col 3</th>
<th>Col 4</th>
</tr><tr><td>10071012008</td><td>2008</td><td>900</td><td>13/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012009</td><td>2009</td><td>950</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012010</td><td>2010</td><td>950</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012011</td><td>2011</td><td>810</td><td>5/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012012</td><td>2012</td><td>908</td><td>6/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012013</td><td>2013</td><td>866</td><td>13/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012014</td><td>2014</td><td>840</td><td>13/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012015</td><td>2015</td><td>850</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012016</td><td>2016</td><td>800</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10071012017</td><td>2017</td><td>760</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr></table> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and paste the code in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: I think I've done that correctly but let me know if something looks wrong.

Comment: I think there are backticks arround your stack snippet (looks like it is in a code block)- if yes remove them...

Comment: I fixed your snippet.But it is missing elements and such. It only have 1 table. Please include [mcve]

Comment: Updated code so there are 3 collapsed tables.  Hope that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you add simply `.active` class, it will not display the content. You have write the CSS code for `.active` class. You have following code

```
.content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

In the above code you are hiding the entire section using `display:none`, but you didn't reopen when you have the `active` class for the parent. So you have to add the following style

```
.collapsible.active .content {
   display:block;
}
```

The above style is checking whenever you have added the `.active` class for the parent (collapsible), the child content will enable.

I am just giving the styles for showing and hiding. Check all the remaining style problems.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
function openWine(evt, wineName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(wineName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 12.6px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
 }
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
   text-decoration: none;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
   text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wp-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wp-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wp-table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.wp-table th:first-child, 
.wp-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 12px;
}


.wp-table td, 
.wp-table th {
    padding: 4px 4px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.wp-table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12.6px
 }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.wp-table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px
 }
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.wp-table {
    font-size: 12.6px!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.wp-table {
    font-size: 15px!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12.6px;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
}
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.collapsible:after {
  content: '+';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active.collapsible:after {
  content: "-";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.noncollapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12.6px;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.noncollapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  margin-top:1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
}
.content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.collapsible.active .content {
  display:block;
}
.noncollapsecontent {
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 1')" id="defaultOpen">Wine 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 2')">Wine 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 3')">Wine 3</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openWine(event, 'Wine 4')">Wine 4</button>
</div>

<div id="Wine 1" class="tabcontent">

<button type="button" class="collapsible">Wine Name/button>
<div class="content">
<table class="wp-table">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
<th>Header 3</th>
<th>Header 4</th>
</tr><tr><td>10060452000</td><td>2000</td><td>4800</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452008</td><td>2008</td><td>2670</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452009</td><td>2009</td><td>2348</td><td>13/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452010</td><td>2010</td><td>3300</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452011</td><td>2011</td><td>2590</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452012</td><td>2012</td><td>3800</td><td>5/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452013</td><td>2013</td><td>2300</td><td>15/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10060452014</td><td>2014</td><td>2320</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
<tr><td>10062052008</td><td>2008</td><td>4332</td><td>14/4/2021</td></tr>
</table> 
</div>
```